# two variables foreach loop problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I want to draw a pulse train on which I write some information like the corresponding angle, etc...
But I think I've got a problem with the two variables foreach loop because I can't even compile since I added this line

```
\addplot[dirac] coordinates {(\temps,0.75)};
```

The entire code is :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  dirac/.style={
    mark=triangle*, mark options={scale=2}, ycomb, scatter, blue,
    visualization depends on={y/abs(y)-1 \as \sign},
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={\scope[rotate=90*\sign,yshift=-2pt]}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded                corners=3pt,font=\scriptsize},
    small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.2}
}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,x=1,xmin=-25,xmax=375,y=100,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  title={Train d'impulsions à 40MHz},ylabel={Tx},xlabel={Temps/ns},
  every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:1)},anchor=near ticklabel},
  every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:1)},anchor=near ticklabel},
  ytickmin=2, xtickmax=350, axis y line=left
  ]

  \foreach \temps/\angle in {0/-21, 25/-18, 50/-15, 75/-12}{
     \edef\temp{\noexpand
     \addplot[dirac] coordinates {(\temps,0.75)};
     \node[small dot,pin={$\angle\degres$}]  at (25+\temps,70) {};}
     \temp
  }

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me.
For my defense, I am a beginner in Tikz-PGF

Comment: I don't think that it is the addition of the plot which is the problem. That seems to work fine. It is the use of `\temps` in the coordinate specification of the additional node for the pin which seems to cause the issue. I can't get `\temps` recognised within `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}` at all...

Comment: Yes you're right. Even without the addplot line, it does not work at all. I get the following error message : "Undefined control sequence. }"

Comment: What I don't understand is that `\temps` seems to work fine in the `\addplot` line itself but even if I just try `\node {\temps}`, it won't work. I don't really use plots much, though, so probably I'm just not understanding how the `axis` environment works....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `axis` environment is postponing evaluation of some things until `\end{axis}`, the variables `\temps` and `\angle` don't exist anymore by then. In that case, you can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` that immediately substitutes the loop counter for any `#1` given in the loop body. The only drawback is that it doesn't support multiple loop variables, so you have to calculate one from the other like this:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,25,...,75}{
  \addplot[dirac] coordinates {(#1,0.75)};
  \node[small dot,pin={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{#1/25*3-21}%
    $\angle\degres$
  }]  at (25+#1,70) {};
}
```

This yields:

[image: Result]

One additional hint: you should probably look at section 4.17 "Custom Annotations" of the `pgfplots` manual to see how you can specify node coordinates in the plot coordinate system using `axis cs`.

---

### Technical details

It seems you tried to force the expansion of `\temps` and `\angle` using `\edef`, but doing so you have to protect anything you don't want expanded with `\noexpand`, which is quite tedious. If you move the creation of the pins out of the axis environment it works, but then it's difficult to line up the pins with the plot...

Besides that, `\temps` seems to be a bad choice for a macro name, although I can't say why. If you remove the `\node` from the loop, it still doesn't work:

```
\foreach \temps/\angle in {0/-21, 25/-18, 50/-15, 75/-12}{
   \addplot[dirac] coordinates {(\temps,0.75)};
}
```

fails with `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line <N>`, for reasons unknown to me. If you rename `\temps` to `\temp` however, it works!

But that still doesn't allow you to use the `\node` command with `\temp` inside the loop. It still complains that `\temp` is undefined, because the `\node` macro is only evaluated at the end of the `axis` environment. One workaround is to manually force the expansion of `\temp` and `\angle` using `\expandafter` like this:

```
\def\LoopBody#1#2{%
  \addplot[dirac] coordinates {(#1,0.75)};
  \node[small dot,pin={$#2\degres$}]  at (25+#1,70) {};
}
\let\EA=\expandafter% For shorter code
\foreach \temp/\angle in {0/-21, 25/-18, 50/-15, 75/-12}{
   \EA\EA\EA\LoopBody\EA\EA\EA{\EA\temp\EA}\EA{\angle}
}
```

This expands first `\angle` to `-21`, then `\temp` to `0` and then `\LoopBody{0}{-21}` (etc). However that is not something I can really recommend because it's difficult to understand and debug. Maybe someone with a better understanding of the `pgfplots` internals can give some more insight as to why this is even necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to answer ! It works well with the '\pgfplotsinvokeforeach' command.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that command. Since you accepted my answer, I'll add info about `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. It doesn't support two loop variables though, does it?

Comment: It doesn't support two loop variables I think.